# salesforce SOQL remove phone format

Tags: apex

I have deployed the custom VF page where i'm checking the entered phone no is present in sales force Account object or not but I'm having an issue to populate the right records.

records stored in contact object is in (112)-234-4444 or 1234567891 format and my soql query is not able to return the correct record.

may i know how i can modify my soql query so that it should remove phone format and match phone no against the contact object.

> Select Id,Account.Phone,cust_name_c From Opportunity where
>   Account.Phone like \'' +searchParam +'%\' ';

Comment: You say are searching phone number in the Contact object but your code snippet is selecting Account phone from Opportunity.  What exactly are you trying to search?

Comment: thanks for correcting , I'm referring account object to populate the phone no and account is tied to opportunity.

Comment: Please read up on **`SOQL Injection`**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SOQL to find phone numbers. Instead, use SOSL to find the accounts, then query the opportunities:

```
Account[] accts = [find :searchParam in phone fields returning account(id)][0];
Opportunity[] opps = [select account.phone, cust_name__c where accountid = :accts];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just that you need to check for either version of the number, you can use a `in` statement.  I've never tested whether SOQL already does this, but here's the format:

```
string phone = '1231231234';
string phoneFormat = '(123) 123-1234';
Opportunity opp = [select ID from Opportunity where Account.Phone in (:phone, :phoneFormat)];
```

Here's some quick methods to convert them:

```
public static string convertToFormatted(string phone)
{
    return '(' + phone.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + phone.substring(3, 6) + '-' + phone.substring(6, 10);
}

public static string convertFromFormatted(string phone)
{
    string ret = '';
    for(integer i = 0, len = phone.length(); i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(phone[i].isNumeric())
        {
            ret += phone[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response,  is there any other out of the box solution , I don't want to write a code for such a simple thing . thanks again

Comment: @kiran If you consider international numbers, it's less simple than you think.  That said, I'm somewhat surprised that the platform doesn't store phone numbers as a numeric string and format them when the page is viewed.